# daterangepicker timepicker not applying after press the Apply button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, daterangepicker

I used Daterangepicker and timepicker in that after i click the apply button it show only selected date not time. i need bothe selected date and time anyone help me. my code is,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#config-demo').daterangepicker({
        locale: {
            format: 'DD/MMM/YYYY'
        },
        "singleDatePicker": true,
        "timePicker": true,
        "timePickerIncrement": 10,
        startDate: '<?php echo date("m-d-Y"); ?>', //09-21-2016
    }, 
    function(start, end, label) {
        $('#config-demo').val(start.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
    });
}); 

$("#config-demo").on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, Picker) {
    $('#config-demo').val(Picker.startDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: change format to 'DD/MMM/YYYY H:i:s'

Comment: if you want time too so why are you using `format: 'DD/MMM/YYYY'`? Its formeting the date time to this format thats why the tie is truncated. Change the format and include time as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass **time(H:i:s)** parameter with the date format

Try below code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#config-demo').daterangepicker({
locale: {
format: 'DD/MMM/YYYY hh:mm:ss A'
},
"singleDatePicker": true,
"timePicker": true,
"timePickerIncrement": 10,
startDate: '<?php echo date("m-d-Y"); ?>', //09-21-2016
}, 
function(start, end, label) {
$('#config-demo').val(start.format('DD-MM-YYYY  hh:mm:ss A'));
});
}); 
$("#config-demo").on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, Picker) {
$('#config-demo').val(Picker.startDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY  hh:mm:ss A'));
```

Comment: i used this code DD-MM-YYYY  hh:mm:ss its working but i need to show am or pm

Comment: pass A in format format: 'DD/MMM/YYYY H:i:s A' check if it works

Comment: At last got an answer,

Comment: great to help keep helping :)